# Significance of the 'distinction' between 'subjects' and 'predicates'

Tags: subjects, predicate

I have always read that:

> the **"subject"** is the **doer** in the sentence and **everything except the subject** is the **"predicate."**

But being a learner I have never been able to understand the **significance** of this **classification into subjects and predicates.**

While other **classifications** like **gender, number, parts of speech** are very obvious.

What is the thing that makes a **subject** stand out from all others in a sentence?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to read more about the syntax of English, and then you'll have a better idea of those things.

Comment: @LucianSava I have read quite a lot but things seem confusing. Your words may help me a lot.

Comment: You've already given one reason, i.e. that it is denotes the actor (your 'doer' of the action). Another, of course, is that the actor controls the verb.

Answer (score 1):

Predicates are important because they contain the most crucial part of the sentence - *a verb.*

> *I love walking on lawns and humming a song*

Here, subject is *I* and the verb is *love* but with those two words, the sentence is incomplete and half baked.

Predicate helps us understand the sentences and reveal what the subjects do. With subjects doing nothing, the sentence looks cracked.

> *Harry drew his car to the mechanic for a quick fix*

In no time you see that the verb is 'drew' referring to Harry, the subject. Predicate is all other words (including the verb) except the subject. Now, you have a clear idea about the 'action' of the subject, the whole scene.

That's why, predicate are the most important part of a sentence. In fact, without predicate, there is no sentence!

Comment: Is this the case for big complex sentences also?

Comment: An adverb describes a 'verb' not the 'subject' is it still a predicate?

Comment: Your English, @Maulik V, is not very good.